# How to match list in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

example my dataframe,

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 ...
0  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V
1  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   A  
2  V  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U
```

and my list

```
mylist = ['A', 'B' 'C']
```

I want to match the columns and the list so that only the characters in the list exist in the column.

**output what I want**

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 ...
0  A  B  C  
1  B  C                                                                      A  
2     A  B  C
```

I'm not sure what to do, so I ask a question.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = df.where(df.isin(mylist), '')
print (df)
   0  1  2  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
0  A  B  C                                                   
1  B  C                                                     A
2     A  B  C
```

Or if invert mask is possible use:

```
df[~df.isin(mylist)] = ''
```

Comment: hi @jezrael, It's made as an example, so it doesn't apply well. Can I ask you by email with actual data attached?

Comment: @ybin - OK, if not match well it seems data relate problem.

Answer (score 2):

This might also work -

```
df = df[df.isin(mylist)].fillna('')
```